# What does this cmd file do?

Tags: batch-file

I found this cmd file in the CnC Generals Zero Hour Jimbus Edition. I am a newbie to batch language and don't know what the batch file does.

Would I need to run this in order to play my game?

When should I run this file?

```
@echo off
title CnC Generals and Zero Hour -Jimbus edition-
echo.
echo.
echo Se van a crear accesos directos e introducir los oportunos
echo datos en el registro para el usuario activo.
echo.
echo Pulse cualquier tecla para continuar o cierre esta ventana
echo para salir.
pause >nul
if exist "%userprofile%\Documents" goto vista
if exist "%userprofile%\My Documents" goto xp64
if exist "%userprofile%\Mis documentos" goto xp32
shortcuts.exe
echo.
echo.
echo El proceso ha terminado exitosamente, aunque no se
echo han podido instalar nuevos mapas ("maps.7z") ni el
echo mod SECONDWAVE ("SecondWave.7z") porque no se ha
echo ha encontrado la carpeta "Mis documentos".
echo.
echo.
pause
exit
:vista
7za.exe x -y "#leeme#\mapsZH.7z" -o"%userprofile%\Documents"
7za.exe x -y "#leeme#\mods\SecondWave.7z" -o"%userprofile%\Documents"
shortcutSWvista.exe
del /f /q "%userprofile%\Documents\Command And Conquer Generals Zero Hour Data\del.txt" >nul
goto finfin
:xp64
7za.exe x -y "#leeme#\mapsZH.7z" -o"%userprofile%\My Documents"
7za.exe x -y "#leeme#\mods\SecondWave.7z" -o"%userprofile%\My Documents"
shortcutSWxp64.exe
del /f /q "%userprofile%\My Documents\Command And Conquer Generals Zero Hour Data\del.txt" >nul
goto finfin
:xp32
7za.exe x -y "#leeme#\mapsZH.7z" -o"%userprofile%\Mis documentos"
7za.exe x -y "#leeme#\mods\SecondWave.7z" -o"%userprofile%\Mis documentos"
shortcutSWxp32.exe
del /f /q "%userprofile%\Mis documentos\Command And Conquer Generals Zero Hour Data\del.txt" >nul
:finfin
shortcuts.exe
del /f /q del.txt >nul
if exist "%commonprogramfiles(x86)%" goto 64bits
echo.
echo.
echo Sistema de 32 bits
echo.
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\EA GAMES\Command and Conquer Generals Zero Hour" /f /t REG_SZ /v DisplayName /d "Command and Conquer Generals Zero Hour" >nul
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Electronic Arts\EA Games\Command and Conquer Generals Zero Hour" /f /t REG_SZ /v Language /d english >nul
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Electronic Arts\EA Games\Command and Conquer Generals Zero Hour" /f /t REG_SZ /v UserDataLeafName /d "Command and Conquer Generals Zero Hour Data" >nul
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Electronic Arts\EA Games\Command and Conquer Generals Zero Hour" /f /t REG_SZ /v InstallPath /d "%cd%"\ZeroHour\
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Electronic Arts\EA Games\Command and Conquer Generals Zero Hour" /f /t REG_DWORD /v Version /d 00065540 >nul
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Electronic Arts\EA Games\Command and Conquer Generals Zero Hour" /f /t REG_DWORD /v MapPackVersion /d 00065536 >nul
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Electronic Arts\EA Games\Generals" /f /t REG_SZ /v InstallPath /d "%cd%"\Generals\ >nul
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Electronic Arts\EA Games\Generals" /f /t REG_SZ /v Language /d english >nul
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Electronic Arts\EA Games\Generals" /f /t REG_DWORD /v MapPackVersion /d 00065536 >nul
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Electronic Arts\EA Games\Generals" /f /t REG_DWORD /v Version /d 00065544 >nul
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Electronic Arts\EA Games\Command and Conquer Generals Zero Hour\ergc" /f /t REG_SZ /ve /d "4EFFYZNG6AS43QJQ44YG" >nul
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Electronic Arts\EA Games\Generals\ergc" /f /t REG_SZ /ve /d "1743703041400199090005" >nul
goto last
:64bits
echo.
echo.
echo Sistema de 64 bits
echo.
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\EA GAMES\Command and Conquer Generals Zero Hour" /f /t REG_SZ /v DisplayName /d "Command and Conquer Generals Zero Hour" >nul
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Electronic Arts\EA Games\Command and Conquer Generals Zero Hour" /f /t REG_SZ /v Language /d english >nul
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Electronic Arts\EA Games\Command and Conquer Generals Zero Hour" /f /t REG_SZ /v UserDataLeafName /d "Command and Conquer Generals Zero Hour Data" >nul
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Electronic Arts\EA Games\Command and Conquer Generals Zero Hour" /f /t REG_SZ /v InstallPath /d "%cd%"\ZeroHour\ >nul
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Electronic Arts\EA Games\Command and Conquer Generals Zero Hour" /f /t REG_DWORD /v Version /d 00065540 >nul
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Electronic Arts\EA Games\Command and Conquer Generals Zero Hour" /f /t REG_DWORD /v MapPackVersion /d 00065536 >nul
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Electronic Arts\EA Games\Generals" /f /t REG_SZ /v InstallPath /d "%cd%"\Generals\ >nul
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Electronic Arts\EA Games\Generals" /f /t REG_SZ /v Language /d english >nul
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Electronic Arts\EA Games\Generals" /f /t REG_DWORD /v MapPackVersion /d 00065536 >nul
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Electronic Arts\EA Games\Generals" /f /t REG_DWORD /v Version /d 00065544 >nul
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Electronic Arts\EA Games\Command and Conquer Generals Zero Hour\ergc" /f /t REG_SZ /ve /d "4EFFYZNG6AS43QJQ44YG" >nul
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Electronic Arts\EA Games\Generals\ergc" /f /t REG_SZ /ve /d "1743703041400199090005" >nul
:last
cls
echo.
echo  El proceso ha terminado exitosamente y se han
echo  creado accesos directos en "INICIO\PROGRAMAS".
echo.
echo  Pulse cualquier tecla para salir.
pause >nul
```

PS: Batch file includes Spanish.

Answer (score 2):

(edit)
Yes this is a necessary component for your game to be installed. It could also be a component that your game calls during game play. Most likely it's just part of the installation.

This is indeed a batch file. A batch file is a command for any Windows machine, it's a routine of instructions and acts very much like any executable file. The Spanish you refer to is an output message to user (e.g. You are now executing this file!), or as in your file on line 5:
echo Se van a crear accesos directos e introducir los oportunos

echo is a command in this executable file to print a message to the screen.

By the looks of the rest of the (what you call) "cmd" file, it has commands to install other executable files in that particular file folder. So in short, yes this is a necessary file.

And to answer your other question. I am assuming that this batch file is to be called by the install executable and the batch file will execute as desired by the programmer.

Note:

line 32 in your image --

7za.exe x -y "#leeme#\mapsZH.7z" -o"%userprofile%\My Documents"


 is stating this: execute this file 7za.exe with 5 arguments ("x -y #leeme#\mapsZH.7z" -o "%userprofile%\My Documents"). That is standard programming knowledge of a command line argument being passed to an executable.

Answer (score 0):

This does a few things.  The "echo" statements simply show a message on the screen (except for the "@echo off", which is a special case that makes the batch file be less noisy).  The `7za.exe x -y "#leeme#\mapsZH.7z" -o"%userprofile%\Documents"` extracts files from a file named `#leeme#\mapsZH.7z` assuming that 7-Zip is already installed.  Any already-existing files will be overwritten (the "-y" says "yes" to overwriting prompts.)  The `-o` is being used to specify that the output will go to the user profile's "My Documents" directory.  (The word "directory" is used to describe the same thing as a "folder".)

Interestingly, 7za is the name of 7-Zip for Unix.  The official 7-Zip package has an executable called "7z.exe".  But since 7-Zip is open source, I suppose this game could have come with a custom variation.

In theory, this could overwrite files in your My Documents directory.  However, that probably won't cause problems if the referenced .7z files are not malicious.  If the contents of those .7z files are just game-related data, in sensible locations like a subdirectory that is named after the game, then you shouldn't have problems with your own documents being deleted (assuming that you don't place your own documents in the same location, and use the same filename, as whatever is in the .7z file).

There are multiple .7z files mentioned; the others act similarly.

The "REG ADD" lines add information to the registry.  None of that looks terribly suspicious since all the added stuff is going into `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Electronic Arts\EA Games\`

Some of the remaining lines include:
title CnC Generals and Zero Hour -Jimbus edition-
shortcuts.exe
shortcutSWvista.exe
shortcutSWxp64.exe
shortcutSWxp32.exe
shortcuts.exe
del /f /q del.txt >nul

Most of those appear to be running an executable file which is probably custom with the game.  You might be able to just run that executable file directly, instead of running the batch file.  Much of the batch file looks like it is designed to install, by placing files in initial locations and providing basic registry configuration.  However, since these commands (or the 7za command) look like they may be custom, I can't make any promises about exactly what they do.

The `del /f` line does a forceful delete of the file named `del.txt` and does not seem to be prone to delete any other/different files.